# Neuroscience of mathematicians

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy, neurology

I've tried to google this but everything that comes up are things like "mathematical neuroscience" rather than the other way around.

Specifically, I'm interested in the workings of a mathematician's brain that sets her apart from others. For example, is there evidence to be found in MRI scans or EEG recordings of mathematicians as to why they excel in math?

Comment: i think you are looking in wrong direction. Mathematicians are same species as other folks, so look for information on how brain _processes mathematics_, don't bother with occupation. This article might be of interest: http://phys.org/news11473.html It is not _who_ does math, but rather _what_ brain s doing. Or are you interested in how brains of accomplished mathematicians differ from that of artists?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! That is perhaps more of what I'm looking for. Though I'm much more interested in what happens when mathematicians research more abstract stuff than just numbers, like topological or algebraic reasoning. Do you know any research on those things?

Comment: numbers seems pretty abstract to me. Maybe this paper will shed some more light: http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fnhum.2014.00068/abstract

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cognitive science question http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Most people choose a particular subject not just because of an inherent predilection. You should perhaps study the mathematical savants.

Comment: Since when is neurobiology off topic?

Comment: Taking the comments into account I have edited the question to give it more focus. Comparing math versus other disciplines cannot be done at the imaging and electrophysiological level as one needs a control group. Both the math group and control group need to be doing the same task. Comparing a musician playing an instrument versus a mathematician solving a complex mathematical problem is comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: It's not completely off-topic, but the cogsci SE is a *better* fit and the question should logically be there to a) ensure it gets the best possible answers and b) gets the right traffic.

Comment: @GriffinEvo - Neurobiology questions and their overlap with Biology are hotly debated at CogSci. It is definitely on-topic there, but not because it is a better fit there. This question has a strong neuro-anatomy and neurobiology component and it is a borderline-case. Possibly the neurobiology debate needs to be addressed here at Bio as well. Anyway, I edited the question to make it more scientifically sound.

Comment: @AliceD I think it would be a very good discussion for meta - its a part of the SE model to not post the same Q on multiple sites, while both the question, and the site it is on, benefit most by being on the most appropriate site. Personally I'm not sure that it the best way, questions such as this (and many other cogsci type Q's) are suitable for both. I've only raised the close vote because that is how SE is supposed to work, not because I feel the question is massively off topic, just more on topic somewhere else :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**
People competent in mathematics have been shown to have higher activation of the left *angular gyrus* according to fMRI. EEG recordings have shown larger activity in the *posterior parietal cortex*.

**Background**
I think you are interested in **what makes a good mathematician**. A brain imaging study by [Grabner et al. (2011)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3208209/). showed that the left anterior gyrus was more activated in individuals more competent in math. Specifically, the authors argue that the stronger left AG activity in the more competent subjects reflects a higher proficiency in processing mathematical symbols. The anterior gyrus is involved in mathematical symbol processing.

[image: left angular gyrus]
<sup>Left angular gyrus, lateral view. Source: [Kenhub Neuroanatomy Atlas](https://www.kenhub.com/en/atlas/gyrus-angularis)</sup>

ERP studies (event-related potentials deduced from the EEG) have shown higher activity in posterior parietal cortex in subjects excelling in math [(Waisman et al., 2014)](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10763-014-9513-5#page-1). This region is associated with algebra and handling mathematical functions.

[image: Posterior parietal cortex]
<sup>Posterior parietal cortex among other regions not relevant to the question answer. Source: [Live Science](http://www.livescience.com/7110-store.html)</sup>

**References**
[Grabner et al. *Front Hum Neurosci* 2011; **5**: 130](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3208209/)
[Waisman et al., *Int J Sci Math Edu* 2014; **12**(3): 669-96](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10763-014-9513-5#page-1)

Comment: What type of Algebra? Algebra that everyone learns is a low form of mathematics. Being able to process Algebra doesn't necessary equate to a high competence in math. However, if by Algebra, you mean Abstract Algebra, Algebraic Geometry, Lie Algebras, Sigma Algebras, etc. this would be a different story. So what is meant by Algebra since I would be skeptical to someone simply good in Algebra $x+3 =5$ equates to math greatness.

Comment: Quoting from the study: "A computerized test that required of the participants a translation between symbolic and graphical representations of function was designed with 60 tasks (trials) using E-Prime software. [...] The tasks we used in our study are basic items for the Israeli curriculum and were learned by all study participants in a similar way."

Comment: I actually think that this is a fairly good compromise. If we delve too deep into higher mathematics the available pool of subjects diminishes rapidly; on the other hand function manipulation is much closer to actual mathematical research than the plain numericity studies that @aandreev has been pointing out in his comments.

Comment: @dustin - I tried to keep the answer short and sweet without too much detail on methods. But I am happy to edit.I

Comment: @SorcererofDM Israeli curriculum at what level? Even if it is just college math for non math majors, I don't think that reflects a mathematicians brain. If it is high school, that is substantial worse. All subjects should be MS, PhDs, Post Docs, and Professors (hence PhD). Anyone else else shouldn't be referred to as a Mathematician and mathematicians will say MS holders aren't mathematicians either but including wouldn't be wrong.

Comment: In the US, the Bureau of Labor Statistics says a [Mathematician](http://www.bls.gov/ooh/math/mathematicians.htm) typically needs a Masters Degree.

Comment: @AliceD, it is great, that you use Kenhubs image. But please also use the correct link for source: https://www.kenhub.com/en/atlas/gyrus-angularis

Comment: @dustin - the problem, as AliceD mentioned, is that we can't test, say a categorical theorist and a musician, on proving the Yoneda lemma. So we need a task that should use similar faculties in all people, regardless of what occupation they have. Perhaps questions from math competitions would be more appropriate than from the standard curriculum, but olympiad problems are quite different from problems arising from mathematical research.

Comment: @SorcererofDM we can't call something neuroscience of mathematicians if the subjects are layman. Would you say neuroscience of doctors (MDs) if we based it on the educational level of anatomy 1?

Comment: @dustin - I think we are parsing "neuroscience of mathematicians" differently. You want to find out the difference between fields medalists and the "regular Joe" mathematicians. I'd be interested in this question too, though I can't see an easy way to randomize this, or even how to test this. After all, fields medalists are known for building grand and important theories, not for solving problems in one sitting.

Comment: @SorcererofDM I am not talking about field medalists. I am talking about mathematicians. People who simply take a math course are not mathematicians.

Comment: @dustin - so now I'm confused. What is the question you are trying to answer? What is the quality about mathematicians you want to extract? Do you want to separate the good mathematicians from the average mathematicians, or to separate mathematicians from nonmathematicians?

Comment: Perhaps I was misleading in my previous reply. By fields medalists I simply mean much better mathematicians than the average. I probably should have added "for example" in there.

Comment: @SorcererofDM I am not asking any questions. Your title doesn't jive with what you want as an answer. The word mathematician means mathematicians not people who take math courses. They are totally different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23301/discussion-between-sorcererofdm-and-dustin).